# Song titles and copyrights

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, music, copyright-transfer

As the copyright owner of a song, can another artist decide to change its title? Or should that be open to change by a performer who wants to perform the song?

Comment: With apologies to the Gershwins, it ain't necessarily so! And what's more, you say either and I say either; you say neither and I say neither; either, either; neither, neither; Let's call the whole thing off.

Comment: While titles aren't really protected, a right of attribution is in most countries other than the U.S. under the concept of "moral rights". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights

Answer (score 3):

Copyright doesn't prevent others from calling your work whatever they want to call your work.

Look at [17 U.S. Code § 106](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106), which lists the rights exclusively reserved to the copyright owner.